# ACM certificate for domain with SSL from let's encrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53

I own a domain on a site other than Route53 that has SSL issued by Let's encrypt. I have created a new hosted zone for it on Route53 and hooked up the appropriate DNS. I wanted to generate a public ACM certificate for it, but the pending validation status has persisted for a day, where it should take about 30 minutes. What could be the reason that the validation does not want to complete?

Comment: "hooked up the appropriate DNS" - do the name server records for your domain point at Route 53, or do you have another DNS provider? You need to create the ACM validation record where your domain's DNS zone is hosted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks